$\mathbb P^1$-bundle on a partial flag variety
Let $X$ be the partial flag variety of flags $0 \subset V_k \subset V_{k+2} \subset V$ where $V$ is a fixed vector space of dimension $n$ and ${\rm dim} V_k = k$ and ${\rm dim} V_{k+2} = k+2$. Is it possible to say something (for example find a vector bundle $Q$ on $X$ such that $R=\mathbb P(Q)$) about the $\mathbb P^1$-bundle $R$ over $X$ whose fiber consists of subspaces $W$ of dimension $k+1$ such that $V_k \subset W \subset V_{k+2}$? What I care about is to identify the type of the Hirzebruch surface obtained by restricting this $\mathbb P^1$-bundle to a certain rational curve in $X$.

If $\mathcal{U}_k \subset \mathcal{U}_{k+2} \subset V \otimes \mathcal{O}$ is the flag of tautological subbundles then
$$
Q = \mathcal{U}_{k+2} / \mathcal{U}_k
$$
is one of the possible choices.
